# Alfresco Share web-preview collapsed issue

Tags: javascript, share, alfresco, document-preview

I'm using Alfresco 4.2b

I've a issue. When using some browsers (chrome by now) the document preview shows collapsed (it have the document but it is at 38px height)

The div that contains the embed field has a height in "style" that is always in 38px (also if i try to change it in firebug, it returns to 38px)

```
<div id="template_x002e_web-preview_x002e_document-details_x0023_default-full-window-div" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 226px; width: 824px; height: 38px;" class="web-preview real">
    <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="/share/components/preview/WebPreviewer.swf" width="100%" height="100%" style="" id="WebPreviewer_template_x002e_web-preview_x002e_document-details_x0023_default" name="WebPreviewer_template_x002e_web-preview_x002e_document-details_x0023_default" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent" flashvars="fileName=Minuta2.docx&amp;paging=true&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fintra.jaimeillanes.cl%2Fshare%2Fproxy%2Falfresco%2Fapi%2Fnode%2Fworkspace%2FSpacesStore%2F0a41947e-5054-4c6d-a861-caa7b0bb07e2%2Fcontent%2Fthumbnails%2Fwebpreview%3Fc%3Dforce%26lastModified%3Dwebpreview%253A1356554282043&amp;jsCallback=Alfresco.util.ComponentManager.get('template_x002e_web-preview_x002e_document-details_x0023_default').plugin.onWebPreviewerEvent&amp;jsLogger=Alfresco.util.ComponentManager.get('template_x002e_web-preview_x002e_document-details_x0023_default').plugin.onWebPreviewerLogging&amp;i18n_actualSize=Tama%C3%B1o%20actual&amp;i18n_fitPage=Adaptar%20a%20la%20p%C3%A1gina&amp;i18n_fitWidth=Adaptar%20a%20lo%20ancho&amp;i18n_fitHeight=Adaptar%20a%20lo%20alto&amp;i18n_fullscreen=Pantalla%20completa&amp;i18n_fullwindow=Maximizar&amp;i18n_fullwindow_escape=Pulse%20la%20tecla%20Esc%20para%20salir%20del%20modo%20de%20pantalla%20completa&amp;i18n_page=P%C3%A1gina&amp;i18n_pageOf=de&amp;show_fullscreen_button=true&amp;show_fullwindow_button=true&amp;disable_i18n_input_fix=false">
</div>
```

I've been searching but i can't find anything.

Comment: The problem wasn't with crome but with responsiveness. (When browser was maximized it was right, but if it was smaller, it was collapsed). i had to do some css changes.. In version 4.2c was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to search a bit 'deeper' in Alfresco.

Check the flash previewer freemarker template which is injected in the document-details template (xml). In that ftl or a reference to another one should be the div your referring to.

Answer (score 1):

See https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-16914, is that your issue?

You would be recommended to upgrade to the latest 4.2 version, where I believe it is fixed. Alternatively you could try removing the file `tablet.css` file which it seems triggers the problem (note this could have unintended side-effects, however!).